# (ssg-wsg) - Generating Token in application is rejected by CORS policy

Tags: ssg

I can generate SSG WSG token by using Postman, but I am getting error like "from origin 'myApplication_URL' has been blocked by CORS policy" when I call that API via jQuery Ajax.

How to implement SSG WSG within application.

Answer (score 1):

Are you implementing the API request to be triggered from client's browser, or from your application directly?

It is likely you will get the CORS policy error if you are allowing your client to send the API request directly from their browser. The API request is tied to the credentials of your application, and it should be implemented in that way.

Adding on - please share your request payload and the error stack so that we can have a better idea of what is the issue.

Comment: Yes, I am implementing the API request from my application directly.

Comment: Please, have a look on my other separate answers I provide with screenshots.

Comment: Based on the ongoing discussion I'd reckon you are searching for solutions on how to call OAuth APIs with ASP.NET MVC5? You may want to consider creating a new question on it (or check if StackOverflow has similar queries for ASP.NET development on calling OAuth APIs) as it already deviates from the original question (i.e. on the reason why your request was blocked by CORS policy).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code snippet, you are implementing the API call to be triggered via AJAX from your end user's client browser. When your end user clicks the button, his/her browser is the client initiating the API call.

For API integrations, it is usually server-to-server calls.
Your server application needs to be the one initiating the API call.

SSG Developer Portal had some sample codes for Open Authentication type, using Node.js.
https://github.com/ssg-wsg/community/tree/master/guides/open
That kind of implementation would be a server-to-server API call.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have tried with the link you are providing, but I do not want to use Node.js with my application. So is there any other way to use the API calls directly? Thank you.

Comment: our project is not a pure Node js one, it is ASP.Net MVC 5, so that having problem calling the APIs. Please, guide us with another solution. Kindly.

Comment: I cannot even call with NodeService in ASP.NET Core. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is my request payload. I send request with Open Authentication type credentials.

[image]

**Please, share on how to implement with Open Authentication type in a better way, directly from application with JavaScript.**